# Excel vba error 1004 - insert a formula

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to execute these code in my excel sheet

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=if(SUM(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ")>0;MEDIAN(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ");0)"
```

and i'm get an #1004 error with no more informations. Can anybody eyplain my failure?
I hav some others formulars insert in the same way...thx

EDIT:
My Tables look like that
[image]

This should be a projectmanagement tool - Breitband Delphi Method ;)
So my code goes through all the rows and check in which column the descripton is (level 1,2,3,4).
Next the code is adding the rows 8-12 for example.. here i can enter some informations for the project... and now my script should add the formula at column k-n.

My code is not very nice (as my english :) ) - it is just a prototype..

This is my Loop

```
   i = 5
    canSkip = False
    Do
        ' fist first the level
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & i).Value) Then
            level = 1

            If Not IsEmpty(Range("D" & i + 1)) Then
                ' ye we can - so skip this loop
                canSkip = True
            End If
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("D" & i).Value) Then
            level = 2
            If Not IsEmpty(Range("F" & i + 1)) Then
                ' ye we can - so skip this loop
                canSkip = True
            End If
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("F" & i).Value) Then
            level = 3
            If Not IsEmpty(Range("H" & i + 1)) Then
                ' ye we can - so skip this loop
                canSkip = True
            End If
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("H" & i).Value) Then
            level = 4
            canSkip = False
        End If

        If canSkip = True Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            ' First insert some... and bang it to a group
            ' Insert Formula
            Range("K" & i).Activate
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=min(L" & i + 2 & ":L" & i + 5 & ")"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=max(L" & i + 2 & ":L" & i + 5 & ")"
            'Range("T1").FormulaLocal = insertMedianFormula
            'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=WENN(SUMME(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ")>0;MITTELWERT(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ");0)"
            Range("A" & i + 1).Activate
            For x = 1 To 5
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                If x = 5 Then
                    If level = 1 Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Experte"
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Aufw."
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Bemerkung"
                    ElseIf level = 2 Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Experte"
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Aufw."
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Bemerkung"
                    ElseIf level = 3 Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Experte"
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Aufw."
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Bemerkung"
                    ElseIf level = 4 Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Experte"
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Aufw."
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Bemerkung"
                    End If
                    ' now just bang it to a group
                    ActiveCell.Resize(5, 10).Rows.Group
                End If
            Next x
            i = i + 6
        End If

        ' are we finshed?
        If i > lastUsedRow Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        canSkip = False
    Loop
```

Comment: Yes i copied the formula from my example sheet and just add the variables..

Comment: it is a loop which goes through the rows. I have some other formulas which works with the i variable

Comment: There is no protection ;)

Comment: @Tobias what's wrong with Maciej Los answer? It is actually that the problem, could you explain why it didn't work for you?

Comment: Just give me 5 minutes.. i will add some lines ;)

Answer (score 1):

Original formula (MS standard) uses "**,**" instead of "**;**"

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=IF(SUM(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ")>0,MEDIAN(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & "),0)"
```

or use:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).FormulaLocal = "=IF(SUM(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ")>0;MEDIAN(N" & i + 2 & ":N" & i + 5 & ");0)"
```

Please, refer this:
[Formula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
[FormulaLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

**[EDIT]**

First of all...
[IsEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227%28v=office.15%29.aspx) indicates whether a variable (of variant) has been initialized. So, if you want to check if cell is empty (does not contains any value), use:

```
Range("B" & i)<>""
```

Second of all..
Your code has no context. What it means? Using **ActiveCell** or **Range("")** or **Cell()** depends on what workbook (and its sheet) is actually in usage! 
You should use code in context:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
   .Range("A1").Offset(0,i).Formula = "='Hello Kitty'" 
   .Cell(2,i) = "123.45"
End With
```

Third of all...
Review and debug you code and start again using above tips ;)

Comment: This is the correct answer, why has it been downvoted? I replicate @Tobias error with ";" and the code works perfectly fine as Maciej Los wrote. Please tell us what it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know who has downvoted him... i have tried both solutions but i get the same errorcode.. "1004" i don't have more informations about that error

Comment: @Tobias, could you please copy-paste this line into a whatever cell and tell us what does *Excel* (not VBA) says about? `=IF(SUM(N4:N7)>0,MEDIAN(N4:N7),0)`

Comment: There are some more code in my question... i tried both solutions

Comment: @Tobias, the code you, added now wasn't known originally. I'll review it and try to update my answer.